# How to move 2 faces/vertices/edges one into another along one axis

Tags: modeling

[image]

How to move those faces to the middle symetrically, left one selected face along -Y and right one selected face along -Y. Something as Scaling would work but without messing the mesh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do it by first hooking each group of vertices to a separate hook: select, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, *Hook to New Object*:

[image]

Now in *Object Mode* select both hooks, in *Object Constraint Properties* tab [image] add a *Limit Scale* constraint and set **Minimum Y** to `1` (perhaps you want to set the maximum too, if you want to move these groups apart).

[image]

Then press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type *Copy Constraints to Selected Objects* (or choose it from *Objects* -> *Constraints* menu).

Now with both hooks selected, just press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> to scale them along Y axis:

[image]

Comment: I meet this so often in modelling so I thought there must be some faster way, some add-on or something, but this will do too. Thanks!

Comment: There might be one, I just don't know or don't remember.